# How does java array (primitive type) support forEach loop mechanism

Tags: java, foreach, primitive-types

> The question is specific to java 5 or above and below java 8.

**I'm aware that in order to give for-each loop support to a custom class i must implement Iterable interface which is fine and well understood by me.**

But how does java gives the same support to primitive types ,though it applies to java objects too but I'm concerned only primitive types here .
Since java primitive types does not implement Iterable interface . When u create an array of any primitive type let's say **`int`**.

```
int[] intArr = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

How does java gives support to iterate through each element of the above declared array using forEach loop.
i.e., i can do the following thing in java

```
for (int i : intArr) {
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Arrays always support enhanced for loop. This includes primitive arrays.

Comment: May be because of auto boxing int is casted to Integer, similar int array is casted to Integer array and after that for-each works like it does for objects.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  The for-each loop can be used either with an Iterable, or with an array.  That's just the way it was designed.

Comment: @J-Alex, no I don't think they confused those things.  To be able to use a for-each loop on a structure, that structure must _either_ be an array, _or_ be an `Iterable`; and it's been like that since Java 5.  The Java 8 `forEach` method is entirely unrelated.

Comment: I was initially ,while asking the question misunderstood the concept of java supporting for each loop ; which is a class that implements Iterable interface is only class eligible to have for each mechanism.But from above comments it is clear that java supports for each mechanism to arrays irrespective of types and also classes which implement Iterable interface. Finally thanks for the insights :-)